# Split data in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Could anyone please help me to solve a problem, I have a text file, in text file I have below kind off data, and I want to split it to form a dataframe.

```
 Xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x [2 XXXX $123.45 10.1000 $10.20
```

First split has to be from [2 and there after SPACES.

Note:- I've multiple rows of same format.

## Mycode

```
  library (tesseract)
  filename= "test.pdf"
  file <- pdftools::pdf_convert(filename, dpi=500)
  text <- tesseract::ocr(file)
  cat(text, file="output.txt")

  df= readLines ("output.txt")
 df= data.frame(df)
 df= df[-1,]
```

Now I've above sample in one column and I want to split that as stated above

Dataframe look like this

```
  Xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x |2| XXXX| $123.45| 10.1000| $10.20
```

After pie delimiter it should be a new column

Thanks

Comment: `read.table` should be parsing that correctly, and from there I would expect normal column-selection ([`?Extract`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html)) to do this split.

Comment: If that doesn't work, please provide the code you're using, its output, and what your expected output is.

Comment: `scan` default is to split by spaces and newlines `x <- scan(what = character(), text = ' Xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x [2 XXXX $123.45 10.1000 $10.20')`.

Comment: Also, 1) in your text file you have **one** large text line? 2) Before the `[2` there are 4 groups of `xxxx` plus a `x` (total 5), after you only have 4, one `XXXX` and 3 numbers. How can you form a dataframe with that?

Comment: Thanks for reply... I've edited my question... Now hope it helps you to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make two `strsplit` the first on `[` the second on .

```
tt <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(as.character(df), "\\[")
  , function(x) c(x[1], strsplit(x[2], " ")[[1]])))
tt
#     [,1]                     [,2] [,3]   [,4]      [,5]      [,6]    
#[1,] "Xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x " "2"  "XXXX" "$123.45" "10.1000" "$10.20"
#[2,] "Xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x " "2"  "XXXX" "$223.45" "20.1000" "$20.20"
```

Write to csv

```
write.csv(tt, "file.csv")
```

Data:

```
df <- readLines(con=textConnection("Xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x [2 XXXX $123.45 10.1000 $10.20
Xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x [2 XXXX $223.45 20.1000 $20.20"))
```

Comment: Thanks for code... But getting error..... #Error in strsplit(df, "\\[") : non-character argument

Comment: @Beginner I wrote `"\\["` you wrote `"\["`

Comment: @Beginner And does it disappear when you write `"\\["`?

Comment: It's not disappearing... getting error as stated above Error in strsplit(df, "\\[") : non-character argument.... Double \\ only in comments it's changing

Comment: @Beginner Try `strsplit(as.character(df), "\\[")` - I updated the answer.

Comment: Go it thanks... I've changed to df= do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(as.character(df), "\\[")
  , function(x) c(x[1], strsplit(x[2], " ")[[1]])))... How to save the output to CSV?

Comment: @Beginner I have add this in the Answer.

Comment: You're the best 

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is something you expect:

```
r <- data.frame(t(sapply(df, function(x) 
  c(gsub("(.*?)\\[.*","\\1",x), unlist(strsplit(gsub(".*?\\[(.*)","\\1",x),split=" "))),
  USE.NAMES = F)))
```

then the output looks like

```
> r
                      X1 X2   X3      X4      X5     X6
1 Xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x   2 XXXX $123.45 10.1000 $10.20
2 Xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x   3 XXXX $567.89 11.1234 $21.32
3 Yyyy yyyy yyyy yyyy y   3 yyyy $567.89 11.1234 $21.32
```

**Dummy Data**

```
cat("Xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x [2 XXXX $123.45 10.1000 $10.20", 
    "Xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x [3 XXXX $567.89 11.1234 $21.32",
    "Yyyy yyyy yyyy yyyy y [3 yyyy $567.89 11.1234 $21.32",
    file = "output.txt",
    sep = "\n")
df <- readLines ("output.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks for your code.... I've created a dataframe.. how can I split it... Everything is on a single column...I want to split and create new columns

Comment: @Beginner thanks for the information. Now you can see my updated solution

Comment: It's not working... I'm getting like this c("xxxx xxxx xxxx x", "2", "xxxx", "$123.45", "10.1000", "$10.20") in one column and same way with other rows data. Creating individual columns

Comment: @Beginner I have no idea how it looks like in your `df`. Could you use `dput(df)`? Otherwise nobody knows what format you exactly have in `df`

Comment: Oh forgot to mention that it's class= "factor"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `tidyverse`, specifically `separate` from the `tidyr` package.

Here is an example, but you would have to generalize according to your specific requirements.

The first `separate` splits your variable at the `[` character. Note that it removes the original string (the `my_string` variable).

Then, the second `separate` deals with the new variable called `str2` (which was generated by the first `separate` call).

You can continue this according to requirements, and then proceed to changing your variables (e.g., the $ should be numbers and so on).

```
library(tidyverse)

example_tibble <- tibble(my_string = c("Xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x [2 XXXX $123.45 10.1000 $10.20",
                                       "yyyy yyyy yyyy yyyy y [3 yyyy $123.45 10.1000 $10.20",
                                       "zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz z [6 zzzz $123.45 10.1000 $10.20"))

example_tibble %>% 
  separate(col = my_string, into = c("str1", "str2"), sep = "\\[") %>% 
  separate(col = str2, into = c("num1", "str3", "price", "num2", "some_other_price"), sep = " ", remove = F)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>   str1           str2             num1  str3  price  num2  some_other_price
#>   <chr>          <chr>            <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>           
#> 1 "Xxxx xxxx xx~ 2 XXXX $123.45 ~ 2     XXXX  $123.~ 10.1~ $10.20          
#> 2 "yyyy yyyy yy~ 3 yyyy $123.45 ~ 3     yyyy  $123.~ 10.1~ $10.20          
#> 3 "zzzz zzzz zz~ 6 zzzz $123.45 ~ 6     zzzz  $123.~ 10.1~ $10.20
```

P.S., for future reference know that the question is not very clear, and you should have provided a better minimal example, and an example to the desired outcome.

Comment: Sorry for creating confusion... I've modified my question hope it helps or let me know how can I help further